# Unable to find element using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium webdriver for practice writing script  on naukri.com website.

I want to click on 'Attached Resume' link on left side under update profile but is says "Unable to locate element".
I have tried to find the element with xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Attached Resume")).click();
```

I have even tried with class got same error.

Here is the HTML sample

```
<div id="leftNav_updateProfile" class="leftNavBullet">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="//my.naukri.com/Profile/edit?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/Profile/editSummary?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/EmploymentDetails/add?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/Profile/view/subAction/ar?id=&altresid=#ar">
<span class="gryTxt">• </span>
Attached Resume
</a>
<a href="//my.naukri.com/ITProjects/add?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/ITSkills/edit?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/EducationDetails/edit?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/ProfileShowcase/edit?id=&altresid=">
<a href="//my.naukri.com/OtherInfo/edit?id=&altresid=">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
package practice;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class UploadResume {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Login']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("eLogin")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("pLogin")).sendKeys("12345");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='leftNav_updateProfile']//a[contains(.,' Attached Resume')]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("uploadLink")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("attachCV")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share `HTML` sample?

Comment: did we need a space before the Attached Resume?

Comment: @nirmala Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB please check I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

As you can see that anchor tag has text "." in the first span, hence link text "Attached Resume" will not work.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="//my.naukri.com/Profile/view/subAction/ar?id=&altresid=#ar">
<span class="gryTxt">• </span>
Attached Resume
</a>
```

**Please use the below Xpath:**

> //div[@id='leftNav_updateProfile']//a[contains(.,' Attached Resume')]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this,

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Attached Resume")).click();
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Attached Resume")).click();
driver.fineElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Attached Resume')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it by using the below Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href ='//my.naukri.com/Profile/view/subAction/ar?id=&altresid=#ar']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Here is the working code to open the URL **`https://www.naukri.com/`**, log in through valid credentials and click on **`Attached Resume`** link:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q44732783_Naukri {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Login']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("eLogin")).sendKeys("unix.dev.qa@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pLogin")).sendKeys("iamthebest");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']")).click();
        WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='leftNav_updateProfile']//a[contains(.,' Attached Resume') and not(@class='gryTxt')]"));
        myelement.click();

    }

}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you but it still says "unable to locate element"

Comment: @nirmala I met the same but inducing `implicitlyWait` solved it for me. Increase the `ImplicitlyWait` or add some `ExplicitWait`, the code works fine. Thanks